# inverse engineering

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assume that we have a function of two variables. which i dont know its form, i just can get the output of the function . if I want to do the inverse problem, i.e., I was given a value of the function, and I want to tell what inputs of the function are ?  it seems to me that  the problem  might have different solutions. I am an engineer, I am trying to model data into an analytical function.

Comment: Consider the function $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$. Given the output "5", there are plenty of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done.  For a typical $z$ and a "nice" function $f$,   $f(x,y) = z$ corresponds to a curve in the $x,y$ plane.  Just knowing $z$, you can't tell which point $(x,y)$ on that curve was the input.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I thought the same but I thought there might be a way to "get-around" this problem. I understand that the behavior of the function with respect to one variable can be described using the derivative. what if I can get a database of measurements that can serve predicting the input variables.

Comment: In other words, It might be impossible the regular way, but there should be a way practitioners use to solve this problem. I am aware that I am not speaking math anymore, you can not expect much from an engineer.

Comment: To "get around" this problem, you have to change the problem.  You said you were given "a value of the function".  That is not enough to determine the inputs, even if you know the precise form of the function.  If you are given more information, maybe the value of a different function with the same inputs, then it might be possible to determine the inputs.  But you'd have to tell us what the additional information is.